# Connecting MySQL with Crystal Reports v10

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to Crystal Reports v10 and I'm creating reports to embed in Visual Studio 2010 forms. The database server I'm using is MySQL. I have some issues regarding to creating new connection in crystal reports. Based on what I've read, I should select the ODBC in order for me to connect it to the MySQL. However, when I select ODBC and LocalServer and enter the username and password an error message occurred and shows **Logon Failed**. Am I doing it right? Is there anything you could help me please?

I already installed the **MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [MySQL ODBC Connector.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).  Create an ODBC data source from the Administrative Tools \ ODBC Data sources control panel.  It will then be available in Crystal Reports.

Comment: @sean Did you also create a user or system data source in the ODBC Data Sources control panel?

Comment: Programs\Administrative Tools\ODBC data sources. If you don't have it, check the Programs & Features panel to add windows components.  Also just try typing "ODBC" into the Win7 start menu search

Comment: Thanks. I am already connected with data sources.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must download the appropriate version of mysql odbc connector since there are two of them:

1. mysql odbc connector Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer)
2. mysql odbc connector Windows (x86, 64-bit), MSI Installer)

if 64-bit doesn't run, try to uninstall it and try the 32 bit msi Installer

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/