# Prompts Login window in Crystal Report in ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, crystal-reports

1. I am using VS 2012
2. MySql
3. mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-win32.msi

   4.crystal report runtime on windows server 2008.

My web application works fine in my development system, but after deployment to Windows server 2008 , crystal reports ask for addition information about login information as given in following screen.
[image]

**using the following code.**

```
    string databaseName = "hr";
    string serverName = "192.168.137.6";
    string userID = "co";
    string pass = "password";
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfo TabLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        TableLogOnInfos  TabInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/GeneralEmpReports/ddoWiseEmpRpt.rpt");
        string ddoCode = tbx_ddoCode.Text.ToUpper();
        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
        reportDocument.SetParameterValue("D", ddoCode);


        conInfo.ServerName = serverName;
        conInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
        conInfo.UserID = userID;
        conInfo.Password = pass;
        conInfo.AllowCustomConnection = false;
        conInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table T in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
        {
            TabLogOnInfo = T.LogOnInfo;
            TabLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
            T.ApplyLogOnInfo(TabLogOnInfo);
        }

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.AutoDataBind = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(80);


    }
```

i don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: because crystal report is not able to access your db

Comment: So then where i am doing mistake?

Comment: check connection string for database

Comment: Same user is also created is mySql on Windows server 2008

Comment: I want to add that i am using OLEDB(ADO) =>> MS OLEDB Provider for ODBC ==>> my database

Comment: where to check connection string? i dont use any connection string, only stored procedure which i use onle as given in above code. i m using DSN , i-e control panel ==>> Administratice tool ==>> Data source (ODBC)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020083/connecting-mysql-with-crystal-reports-v10

Comment: The above link does't help, because i have already created a user DSN , System DSN and File DSN , i have tried all these, these work only in my development system, but does not work on Server PC (Windows server 2008) when i access it from remote on local network, same DSN is also created on Server computer but still prompts for Login

Comment: @KhuramJan I'm facing the exact same problem, did you solve yours? If you did please post it as an answer thanks